# SPA Routing Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, url-routing

I'm doing a SPA project using Vanilla JS. It is a kind of notice board platform where there are categories. Each category will have a list of posts that users have uploaded.

This is the URL format for each category: `base_URL/{category}/{pageNum}`.

This is the URL format for each post: `base_URL/board/${board_id}`.

1. I have to extract the `board_id` some how upon the user clicking it and use it in the URL (ex: `http://example.com/board/31890adfa`).
   From searching I found out I'll be using the history API.
2. Then I'll extract the `board_id` from the URL and send a request to view that post:

```js
const fetchBoardDetails = async (board_id) => {
  await fetch(`http://${base_URL}/board/${board_id}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  }).then(async (res) => {
    const data = await res.json();
    root.innerHTML = `
      <h1>${data.title}</h1>
      <ul>
       <li>${data.category}</li>
       <li>${data.date}</li>
       <li>${data.place}</li>
       <li>${data.fee}</li>
      </ul>
    `
}
```

**My problem is, how do I get the `board_id` in step 1 to use in step 2?** I think it has to do with URL routing and I've tried to figure it out but can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: _"I have to extract the board_id"_: from where? Is it `pageNum`?

Comment: That's precisely what I'm confused about. So, in each category page, there is a list of posts. And each post, upon clicking, should display its corresponding page. In order to display the corresponding page, I need the post's `board_id`. And I'm not sure how to "assign" each post in the category page its unique `board_id`.
For example, for a static page, an `<a>` tag can have a hard-coded `href` to go to a particular page. But I'm trying render the posts after retrieving them from the server. And I'm not sure how to dynamically "assign" each post link in the list its corresponding `board_id`.

Comment: I don't see any links here, but if you want to get the path from the URL, try `location.pathname`.